# Зачем ставят _ перед именем файла с расширением scss?

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

Зачем ставят **_** перед именем файла с расширением  scss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

_ пишется перед именем частичных файлов, которые не должны отдельно компилироваться в css, а вложены в какой-то другой scss файл

Answer (score 8):

Это стандартное соглашение по именованию [файлов-составляющих](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials) - они служат частями других файлов. Обычно в них хранят общие mixin'ы, функции, константы и прочее.

SASS не позволяет независимо компилировать их - при попытке этого, он просто выдаст ошибку.